# Connecting to Firestore with Firebase Admin SDK Causes App to Freeze

Tags: python, django, firebase, firebase-admin

I am trying to use Firebase Admin SDK in a Django app using a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances). I followed the instructions as per the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment). However, the app freezes at the point when Firebase Admin SDK is attempting OAuth2 authentication. My code is as follows:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore


cred = credentials.Certificate(key_path)# path to serviceAccountKey
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()

doc_ref = db.collection(u'users').document(u'alovelace') 

# The following causes the app to freeze
doc_ref.set({
    u'first': u'Ada',
    u'last': u'Lovelace',
    u'born': 1815
})
```

The last message displayed in logs is:

```
2022-07-06 06:23:38,519 DEBUG Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
```

The app freezes after that message with no additional info. Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't "follow the instructions", which show that the second argument requires a `projectId`:

```
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
  'projectId': project_id,
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case the initialisation is not done on a Google Cloud Platform. I am using a service account private key to connect my server to Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when running the code using a Celery task (another thread). The cause of the problem seems to be that the Django app is running within a Socket.IO server.